# How to set up Flask on pythonanyhwere based on flask megatutorial

Tags: python, mysql, flask, pythonanywhere, flask-migrate

I am currently developing an application. this web app has its **own domain**. when initially created i set up the domain and the registrar using the cname and it succesfully displayed after a couple of hours **"this is a flask app..."** something like that.

i decided to follow the examples of Mr Grinberg in his book (fully functional on localhost). So i cloned my personal repository to pythonanywhere and ran the following commands.

```
python manage.py db init
python manage.py db upgrade
python manage.py migrate
```

every thing is ok so far. and i checked out the mysql database using **mysql workbench**.

Now comes my issue.

when i run `python manage.py runserver`

it throws me the following error.

```
/home/username/.virtualenvs/webapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:800: UserWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICA
TIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn('SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True to su
ppress this warning.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 20, in <module>
    manager.run()
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/webapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 412, in run
    result = self.handle(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/webapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 383, in handle
    res = handle(*args, **config)
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/webapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_script/commands.py", line 425, in __call__
    **self.server_options)
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/webapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 843, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/webapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 677, in run_simple
    s.bind((hostname, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

i tried disabling the wsgi.py file (commenting everything out) still the same.

Things to know:

1. i have a paid acount.
2. this is the second webapp on pythonanywhere. (the first one is not modeled based on the tutorial and works just fine)

**EDIT**

i changed the port from 5000 to 9000. and it runs in the console. but i cant visit my site. should i comment out the wsgi file?

currently it looks likes this:

```
import sys

# # add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = u'/home/username/e_orders/e_orders'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path

# # import flask app but need to call it "application" for WSGI to work
from manager import app as application
```

**manage.py**

```
import os
from app import create_app, db
from app.models import User
from flask_script import Manager, Shell, Server
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand


app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
manager = Manager(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)


def make_shell_context():
    return dict(app=app, db=db, User=User)

manager.add_command('shell', Shell(make_context=make_shell_context))
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
manager.add_command('runserver', Server(port=9000))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

**EDIT 2**

i have the following error with the wsgi configuration above.

**errorlog**

```
ImportError: No module named manager
2016-08-04 17:42:39,589 :Error running WSGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 154, in __call__
    app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 170, in import_error_application
    raise e
ImportError: No module named manager
```

Comment: which port you are using to run. It says this port is already used.

Comment: i found that the default is port=5000. i will change it and get back to you.

Comment: ok good if it works for you, use ctrl+c to quite else it will produce same error

Comment: what about the wsgi?

Comment: if you are accessing it using http:://hostanme:portnum/.... it means you are in debug mode. WIth wsgi you can use it like http:://hostname/....

Answer (score 2):

PythonAnywhere dev here.

If you run a Flask app from a console on PythonAnywhere, it's not actually accessible from anywhere else.  It may well run, but nothing will route any requests to it.  So there's no need to run anything from the console (unless you're just testing for syntax errors, I guess).

Instead, you need to create a web app on the "Web" tab -- it looks like you've already done that.  This then routes using the WSGI file that you seem to have discovered.

If you've done all that, then when you visit the domain that appears on the "Web" tab (normally something like *yourusername*`.pythonanywhere.com`) then you should see your site.  If you get an error, then check out the error logs (also linked from the "Web" tab), which should help you debug.

[edit: added affiliation]

Comment: So i reloaded it. closed the bash runserver connection. changed the cname on the registrar. but it still does not work. is the wsgi file seem properly configured to you? am i calling the correct app from manager.py

Comment: It might be easier to debug this if I can take a look at your account.  Drop us a line on support@pythonanywhere.com and we can take it from there, and maybe post any generally-useful results back here.

Comment: i fixed it and i will post my answer shortly. thank you all for your insights!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the big delay. The solution to **run the server** is the one bellow.

```
# This file contains the WSGI configuration required to serve up your
# web application at http://<your-username>.pythonanywhere.com/
# It works by setting the variable 'application' to a WSGI handler of some
# description.
#
# The below has been auto-generated for your Flask project

import sys

# # add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = u'/home/username/mysite/'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path

# # import flask app but need to call it "application" for WSGI to work
from manage import app as application
```

i will post the database setup also...